# Модуль для inputs

Tags: c++

Какой модуль `#include<...>` нужно подключить, чтобы работала функция `inputs`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Функции `inputs` в предоставляемых языком `C++` средствах нет.*

Предполагаю, что вы хотите воспользоваться средствами для `I/O`, поэтому рекомендую к прочтению следующий [**референс.**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<studio.h>
```

Но не уверен.